# Как сделать внутриигровую покупку, для отключения рекламы? Game dev

Tags: ios, objective-c, разработка-игр, swift

Добавил в свою игру рекламу, и хочу сделать платную версию без рекламы. Как это можно осуществить? Платформа: ios, язык: swift
Может есть гайд какой-нибудь, как это вообще все происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На свифте вряд ли найдется пример, а objC сколько угодно.

Вкратце, как оно происходит:

- В Capabilities приложения включить in-app purchases.
- В itunesconnect ввести все объекты, которые собираетесь продавать.
- В приложении подключит StoreKit.framework
- Написать код, который соберет вместе (при нажатии этой кнопки, купить этот объект).

[Вот хороший пример.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/84359/)

Comment: Спасибо, изучу на досуге. т.е. получается нужно выкладывать еще одно приложение, которое платное и без рекламы? или все это делается в рамках одного приложения?

Comment: в одном приложении. создаете объект non-consumable. и когда получаете информацию, что он куплен, сохраняете, например в user defaults, и перестаете показывать рекламу.